# IOexception while running bash commands through ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am getting a IOException when trying to run a sed command through Java using a ProcessBuilder:

```
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sed -i 's/hello world//g' 
/home/user/test": error=2, No such file or directory
```

The command is `sed -i 's/hello world//g' /home/user/test`
But the problem isn't the command, I can run the same command through terminal and it would remove the string "hello world"

```
public void removeString(String str, String file) throws IOException {
    String command = "sed -i \'s/" + str + "//g\' " + file;
    System.out.println(command);
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process p = pb.start();
}
```

What is causing the process to be unable to find the file?

Comment: you could try to run the sed binary using its full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` [expects individual arguments to be sent separately](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29) in the constructor. Try running it like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sed", "-i", "s/hello world//g", "/home/user/test");
```

(You can also pass it a `List<String>` if you want)

It works this way to prevent [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection) security vulnerabilities.